# Karate - What is the easiest way to search the entire response for a string

Tags: karate

I simply want to search the entire response for a string.

The code I am currently using is as follows:

```
And string responseString = response
Then match responseString contains "mySearchString"
```

Is there a way of doing this without having to convert the response to a String so I can do this in 1 line of code instead of 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
Then match karate.toString(response) contains "mySearchString"
```

Comment: Anyway to search for 2 strings in the response? I've tried a few combinations but can't get it to work e.g. Then match karate.toString(response) contains ("mySearchString1","mySearchString2") or Then match karate.toString(response) contains ["mySearchString1","mySearchString2"] or Then match karate.toString(response) contains ["mySearchString1" &&"mySearchString2"] or Then match karate.toString(response) contains ["mySearchString1" || "mySearchString2"].  I can do the search in 2 separate lines of course but was wondering if you can do it in 1.

Comment: @Matt interesting :) sorry, karate can't get any more concise. if you know JS well, you can write a custom function: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#commonly-needed-utilities

Comment: Yes I can do it in JS...was just wondering if Karate can do it. Thanks again :)